# Rails 3 - Optimize form_for in index and show views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have just started learning Rails and I'm trying to build a post/like type feature. I have got it working but there must be a more a efficient way of doing it.

My post index view contains the following code (I'm using jQuery to submit the form via ajax):

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>   
  <%= form_for([post, post.likes.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => post.id %>
  <%= f.submit pluralize(post.likes.count, 'Like'), :class => 'like like-' + post.id.to_s %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

My show view contains the following:

```
<%= render "likes/form" %>
```

Which contains the following:

```
<%= form_for([@post, @post.likes.build]) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
<%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => @post.id %>
<%= f.submit pluralize(@post.likes.count, 'Like'), :class => 'like like-' + @post.id.to_s %>
<% end %>
```

This all works combined with jQuery and destroy links. However having two different forms seems a bit heavy duty. Any ideas on how to change/optimize or the best way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you passing `post_id` as a hidden_field? It will automatically be passed through on account of you using a nested form (`[@post, @post.likes.build]`)

Comment: Hey Ryan, I'm not passing hidden fields anymore, cleaned it up a fair bit with help from @mark and @pjammer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit form.html.erb your form partial

```
<%= form_for([post, post.likes.build]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => post.id %>
  <%= f.submit pluralize(post.likes.count, 'Like'), :class => 'like like-' + post.id.to_s %>
<% end %>

<%= render "likes/form", :locals => {:post => @post} %>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= render "likes/form", :locals => {:post => post} %>
```

Comment: I agree on the hidden field current_user field point made by pjammer as this would be open to abuse. form_for([post... will already build the post id as part of the action (form route) so you can remove that as well.

Comment: thanks, very helpful. i cleaned up the hidden fields and tried the above...but i get a "undefined local variable or method 'post', i'm guessing I need to change something in the controller?

Comment: when trying to load the post views for index and show in the browser

Comment: It should tell you where it's happening, which partial or template and on which line.

Comment: ah right, line one of the form partial...https://skitch.com/davidgoldberg/reqgk/action-controller-exception-caught, really appreciate the help.

Comment: It looks then as if you're not sending the post instance variable as a local variable. Double check the last three lines of my code above.

Comment: changed your code a little to <%= render :partial => "likes/form", :locals => {:post => @post} %>, just added the partial part and seems to work. thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

hidden fields are for noobs man, put that mess in the controller :-)

In your Post controller do something like

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @like = @post.likes.build
end
def create
  @like = @post.likes.build(params[:id])
  @like.user_id = current_user.id
  # ... the rest of the stuff here
  #assuming you have scaffolded it will be here. you can find that
end
```

now in your view you can do something like:

  `< % = form_for([post, @like]) do |f| %>
  < % = render_partial 'likes', :locals => {:f => f} %>
  < % end %>`

in a new `_likes.html.erb`:

     `< % = f.submit pluralize(post.likes.count, 'Like') ,  :c lass = >  'like like-' + post.id.to_s %>`

of course some may not work exactly but this is the gist from what i can gather.

Comment: thanks @pjammer, all cleaned up, know for next time now :)...tried putting in the above in the post create controller...but when i created a post it also built the like. just need to play around a bit more i think.

Comment: You could also do @like = @post.likes.build(params[:like].merge{:user_id => current_user.id})

Comment: I think you should put my code in the Like Controller... i was thinking about that but didn't know the extent of what you were doing.  try it and if it works i'll update this answer.

Comment: Yup the likes controller together with marks answer worked a treat, thanks.